# Pump flow rate calculation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, pumps

How to calculate flow rate of pump and velocity if only given length of pipe and volume of tanks?

Comment: Note you really need to know the viscosity and density of the liquid being pumped. Also the pipe internal diameter. I know this may sound sort of obvious but a thick, viscous liquid will need a lot of pressure to get it through narrow pipes. Any height difference between the inlet and outlet matters too.

Answer (score 0):

The volume of the tank shall give you an indication (if filled) of the level of the fluid stored inside which means that you can calculate the potential energy stored in the fluid which is converted to kinetic energy at tank delivery nozzle (meaning that velocity can be calculated simply using Bernoulli's equation).

You'll then use the length of the pipe to calculate the friction losses (head losses $\triangle h_{loss}$) that is added to the total head requirement of the piping system $\triangle h_{total}$ and finally the power of the pump can be calculated as: $P = \rho gQ \triangle h_{total}$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not providing enough data, but it happens most of the time. I usually assumed pressure drop of 0.1 bar for every 100m pipe length.
From there and pipe size, you have velocity and flowrate.
Tank size is not relevant info.

On second thought, you can just run the pump and stopwatch to empty half volume of tanks. Flowrate = (Volume of half of tanks)/Time.